# CosmosDB - TOP 1 query with ORDER BY - Retrieved document count and RU

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Considering the following query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c 
WHERE c.Type = 'Case' 
AND c.Entity.SomeField = @someValue
AND c.Entity.CreatedTimeUtc > @someTime
ORDER BY c.Entity.CreatedTimeUtc DESC
```

Until recently, when I ran this query, the number of documents processed by the query (RetrievedDocumentCount in the query metrics) was the number of documents that satisfies the first two condition, regardless the "CreatedTimeUtc" or the TOP 1. 
Only when I added a composite index of `(Type DESC, Entity.SomeField DESC, Entity.CreatedTimeUtc DESC)` and added them to the ORDER BY clause, the retrieved documents count dropped to the number of documents that satisfies all 3 conditions (still not one document as expected, but better).

Then, starting a few days ago, we noticed in our dev environment that the composite index is no longer needed as retrieved documents count changed to only one document (= the number in the TOP, as expected), and the RU/s reduced significantly.

My question – is this a new improvement/fix in CosmosDB? I couldn’t find any announcement/documentation on this manner.
If so, is the roll-out completed or still in-progress? We have several production instances in different regions.

Thanks

Comment: Adding an index cannot change the result set, period.  Something else is going on here.

Comment: I read this blog post a few days ago: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/april-query-improvements/. May be the improvement is part of the things covered in this blog.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not talking about the result, the result is consistent. I'm talking about the RetrievedDocumentCount in the query metrics, which is number of document processed by the query (which directly affect the RU/s consumption).

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I have seen the article, but it talks about improvements in Aggregate functions and inequality filters / filters on undefined values, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

There have not been any recent changes to our query engine that would explain why this query is suddenly less expensive.

The only thing that would explain this is fewer results match the filter than before and that our query engine was able to perform an optimization that it would not otherwise be able to have done with a larger set of results.

Thanks.

Comment: Added again the composite index and tested the query with a larger data set - the RetrievedDocumentCount reduced to one document as expected. Thanks